# Zeros of an entire function on the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-functions

> **Question:** Consider a small rectangle as $R_\epsilon=\{x+iy\in\mathbb{C}\mid 1-\epsilon\leq x\leq 1+\epsilon , \ 0\leq y\leq 1+\epsilon\}$ where $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrarily small.
> For a non zero entire function $f(z)$ which is non-zero on the real axis, prove that there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ such that $f(z)$ has no zeros on the boundary of rectangle $R_\epsilon$ whenever $0<\epsilon<\epsilon_0$.

**I tried the following by the method of contradiction:** If possible suppose no such $\epsilon_0$ exists. Then for each $\epsilon>0$, there must exist $\epsilon'$ with $0<\epsilon'<\epsilon$ such that the boundary of the rectangle $R_{\epsilon'}$ has atleast one zero of $f$.

In particular if we take $\epsilon_n=\frac{\epsilon_0^*}{2^n}$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $0<\epsilon_0^*\leq 1$ then there exists $\epsilon_{n}'$ such that $0<\epsilon_n'<\epsilon_n=\frac{\epsilon_0^*}{2^n}$ such that the boundary of $R_{\epsilon_n'}$ has atleast one zero $z_n$ of $f$.

Without loss of generality we may assume $\{\epsilon_n'\}_{n\geq 1}$ is decreasing and $\epsilon_n'\to 0^+$ (To see this choose $\epsilon_1'<\epsilon_1$ and then choose $\epsilon_2'<\epsilon_1'$ and $\epsilon_2'<\frac{\epsilon_0^*}{2^2}$. Next we choose $\epsilon_3'$ such that $\epsilon_3'<\epsilon_2'$ and $\epsilon_3'<\frac{\epsilon_0^*}{2^3}$
and continue this process).

Consider the set $A=\{z_n\in \mathbb{C}\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $z_n$ are zeros of $f$ as chosen above. Now we can have two cases:

Case $1$: $A$ is an infinite set- Since $\epsilon_n=\frac{\epsilon_0^*}{2^n}$ so we have $\epsilon_0^*>\epsilon_1>\epsilon_2>\epsilon_3>...$ and hence the zeros $z_n$ of set $A$ lie in a bounded set which is the rectangle $R_{\epsilon_0^*}$ where $0<\epsilon_0^*\leq 1$ which implies that $A$ is a bounded set.

So by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, set $A$ has a limit point. Since $f$ is entire so by the Identity theorem since $A$ is the set of zeros of $f$ and it has a limit point so $f$ must be identically zero which is a contradiction.

Case $2$: $A$ is a finite set- I am having no clue regarding this.

I request you to please give an elaborated answer. Any other method is also welcome.

Comment: Your work looks good, but maybe I'm not understanding your process; how can A be finite at all? Aren't you choosing an infinite sequence of zeros that get arbitrarily close in real part to 1? And the intersection of all rectangle boundaries is the single point 1+0i, at which f is given to not be zero.

Comment: @OvinusReal I don't know that whether $A$ can be finite or not. Please write an answer. I will happily accept it

Comment: For A to be finite, there is some N such that $n > N \to z_n = z^*$, where $z^*$ is fixed. But then $z^*\in \cap _{n} \partial R_{e_n'}=\{ 1+0i \}$, so $z^*=1$, but $f(z^*)\neq 0$?

Comment: @OvinusReal What do you mean by $n>N\to z_n$? What does tends to mean here?

Comment: @OvinusReal Sorry I could not follow your line "For $A$ to be finite there is some $N$ such that $n>N\to z_n=z^*$

Comment: @OvinusReal - Use "$\implies$" (\implies) instead of "$\to$" (\to). The former denotes logical implication, the latter denotes convergence.

Comment: Oh, I totally missed that. Thanks!